# Object-fit: cover and object-position: 50% 50% do not center image in the middle of the container

Tags: css

I have a container and an image inside of it like this:

```css
.container {
  height: auto;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 500px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://s.tmimgcdn.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/1-9-2.jpg?x47994" alt="">
</div>
```

The image may be larger or smaller than the dimensions of the container depending on the size of the screen. I would like to center the image inside the container using object-fit: cover and object-position: 50% 50%; so that in larger screen sizes it always covers the container and when the container is smaller, it would position itself in the center of the container.

I have noticed that in my example, img object-position does not respond to % values, just pixel values.

EDIT: I'd really like someone to explain to me the behaviour of object-position in my example i.e. why using percentages have no effect on the property.

Comment: margin: 0 auto; on the container is going to position the container, not the image inside of it.

Comment: you want fit the image in full screen or need center img?

Comment: If the container is full screen, I want to make the image to cover the container and by centered in the container

Comment: use container-fluid and then container with image 100%

Comment: What's container-fluid?

Comment: if you are using boostrap frame work their will be container-fluid (its take full width of screen) then add container it fixed width of centrally of screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163941/discussion-between-chirag-solanki-and-jacobdo).

Comment: No need, I am not asking about how it would work in a framework, but rather about a fundamental property in css.

Answer (score 3):

You're simply missing `height: 100%;` on the img styles

Answer (score 2):

Put `heigh:100%` and `width:100%` to the image tag

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: absolute;` and `height: 100%` to your image. So your code will be like this:

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
  min-width: 500px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
  position: absolute;
}
```